# Snowflake not recognizing a CAST or to TO_VARCHAR function over a join key

Tags: sql, join, types, left-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to perform a join across three tables.
This is the initial code, that works but returns all NULL for product description. I figured it is because in the first 2 tables that I am joining the joining key is the varchar type while in the other it is an INT.
The int key is analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product ID (last join).

```
SELECT raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.variant_id
       , raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU
       , raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.price
       , raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.cost_price
       , pc.product_description
FROM raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items 
LEFT OUTER JOIN raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants 
ON raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.variant_id = raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.id
LEFT JOIN analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category as pc ON pc.product_ID = raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.id
GROUP BY raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.variant_id
      , raw.stitch_heroku.spree_variants.SKU
      , raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.price
      , raw.stitch_heroku.spree_line_items.cost_price
      , pc.product_description
```

Next, I tried to use some snowflake function to convert the analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product ID into a varchar.

This is what I tried :

```
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_description
          , T0_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) 
   FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category) as pc
   ON pc.product_ID= sv.id
```

or

```
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_description
   , TRY_CAST(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID as VARCHAR(10) 
   FROM analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category) as pc
   ON pc.product_ID= sv.id
```

The error I have been getting is : Invalid identifier T0_VARCHAR
or Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types NUMBER(38,0) and VARCHAR(10)

I am not sure if there is a way to fix it by doing this or if I just should re upload that file changing the type at its source.

Thank you in advance!!!!

Comment: When I look at your code I have to notice this: 

**T0_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) 
   FROM**

In this part of the code it seems that you have used TO_VARCHAR with number zero 0 and not with letter O ?
TO_VARCHAR
T0_VARCHAR
Please check.

Comment: And for your second attempt I see here : https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/try_cast.html that you have to send a string as an argument for your TRY_CAST function.

Comment: Actually you were right  - dumb mistake to type a 0 instead of a O. That fixed that issue! Thank you. Now I need to figure out on fixing  Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: Great. Would you mind if I put this as an answer and you can mark it as correct ? And for your new problem, If you do not manage it yourself, I suggest to post a new question...

Comment: I cannot see it as a post. I am sorry I am a new user I don't know how I can vote your comment

Comment: but with your points you can only "Accept it". Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I accepted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at your code I have to notice this:

`T0_VARCHAR(analytics.dbt_lcasucci.product_category.product_ID) FROM`

In this part of the code it seems that you have used `TO_VARCHAR` with number zero 0 and not with letter O ? Please check.

And for your second attempt I see here : https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/try_cast.html that you have to send a string as an argument for your `TRY_CAST` function.